# REVTEX 4.1 and PeerX-Press LaTeX workflow

Tags: graphics, conversion, eps, revtex

I am having trouble finding a practical workflow for REVTEX 4.1 documents to be uploaded using the AIP PeerX-press system.

The PeerX system only accepts images in EPS and TIFF format.  My native figure formats are EPS,PNG and JPG.  The problem is that neither pdfLaTeX nor LaTeX can is able to process TIFF files so once I do my final conversions to EPS and TIFF and update all of my includegraphics commands I can no longer render my own document locally.

It is a real pain to maintain two parallel TeX files during the peer review process.  How do people usually overcome this?

I suppose I could also convert raster images to EPS.  This would satisfy both, but I don't have a convenient way to get a reasonably sized compressed EPS with the correct dimensions for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes beloved AIP PeerX-press system :) This is the Makefile for the last paper I submitted to them (it is already published).

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
.SUFFIXES : .tex .dvi .ps .pdf

FILE = amusjmp_submitted

PDFLATEX = /usr/local/bin/pdflatex
BIBTEX = /usr/local/bin/bibtex


PDF = ${FILE}.pdf



.tex.pdf :
        ${PDFLATEX} ${FILE}.tex
        ${BIBTEX} ${FILE}
        ${PDFLATEX} ${FILE}.tex
        ${PDFLATEX} ${FILE}.tex



bib :
        ${PDFLATEX} ${FILE}.tex
        ${BIBTEX} ${FILE}
pdf : bib
        ${PDFLATEX} ${FILE}.tex
        ${PDFLATEX} ${FILE}.tex



# Various cleaning options
clean-ps :
        /bin/rm -f  *.log *.aux *.dvi *.bbl *.blg *.bm *.toc *.out \
        *Notes.bib *.ps
```

Yes converting raster images to EPS is the way to go! [GraphicsMagic](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)
or ImageMagic is your friend here. I have a very strong preference for GraphcisMagic over ImageMagice! No flame wars please! The reasons are of technical nature. Image resizing is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

[`sam2p`](https://code.google.com/p/sam2p/) converts raster images to very well-constructed postscript. The output can sometimes be as much as 100 times smaller than the output of tools such as imagemagick, etc.

That said, the size advantage shouldn't be too important for you: for submission to a journal the file size is rarely important. (I used to care about it because arXiv had pretty strict size limits, but these days the limits are not so bad and anyway I use pdflatex now and compared to EPS, my PDF figures tend to be much better compressed, even when generated by dumb software).

Comment: I agree, the file sizes submitted to the journal do not matter at all.  The important thing is that I can render the same source files through pdfLaTeX to get a reasonably sized PDF without any additional file conversions (other than the internal eps2pdf).  I'll have a look at sam2p.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to first resample my raster image to the appropriate DPI and size. In this case 3.7inches wide at 300dpi. This was done using Preview.app, but ImageMagick could probably also be used. Next I used ImageMagick to convert to an EPS file with compression:

```
convert figure1.png -compress none eps2:figure1.eps
```

My 160kB PNG image resulted in a 3MB EPS file, however the eps2pdf version used by pdfLaTeX is only 245kB so the final PDF is not too large.